# How can I fill a TypeScript File with HTML values?

Tags: html, json, typescript

I have an HTML file in which users can click together a profile. I would like to send this input data to the server as JSON using TypeScript. I already have the **(very) basic** structure in TS, but since I'm still very much in TS, I don't know what to do next.

My HTML code:

```
<div><input type="number" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Enter age" min="0" max="150"/></div>

<div><select name="color" id="color">
  <option value="" disabled hidden selected>Select color</option>
  <option value="red"> red</option>
  <option value="blue"> blue </option>
  <option value="green"> green </option>
  <option value="yellow"> yellow</option>
  </select></div>
```

Typescript:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { AppService } from "./app.service";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"],
  providers: [
    AppService
  ],
})
export class AppComponent {

  public readonly clicked$ = this.appService.buttonHasBeenClicked$;

  public readonly buttonColor$ = this.clicked$.pipe(
    map((clicked: boolean) => clicked ? "primary" : "accent"),
  );

  public constructor(
    private readonly appService: AppService,
  ) {
  }

  public clickButton(): void {
    this.appService.setClickedTrue();
  }

}
```